# how to add external jquery plug in to our website

Tags: jquery, plugins

[image]

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\monic\Desktop\aboutme\simple-text-rotator-master\jquery.simple-text-rotator.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\monic\Desktop\aboutme\simple-text-rotator-master\jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"> </script>
```

Super Simple, Customizable, Light Weight, Easy Text Rotator with Style

$(".rotate").textrotator({
  animation: "dissolve", // You can pick the way it animates when rotating through words. Options are dissolve (default), fade, flip, flipUp, flipCube, flipCubeUp and spin.
  separator: ",", // If you don't want commas to be the separator, you can define a new separator (|, &, * etc.) by yourself using this field.
  speed: 2000 // How many milliseconds until the next word show.
});

how should I include the path???

Comment: Don't you have to add a <div> or a <span> with an id where the plugin should appear? Your desktop path (src) is all it needs if the JS files are in that location.

Comment: I've added those and jquery script as well. But still it doesn't work

Comment: need to use web paths, not hard drive paths

Comment: Also don't need 2 versions of same plugin. `min` just means minified version of the development one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing files on your C drive will lead to a cross-origin error. Instead, I would use CDN's.  Additionally, you do **not** need to include .min.js and .js because .min.js is the same as the .js, just more compressed.  Finally, you also forgot to include the .css file, so I fixed that too.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-text-rotator/1.0.0/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylsheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-text-rotator/1.0.0/simpletextrotator.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the message error in console?

If you aren't using any framework, then your file "myfile.js" must be called relative to your index.html(Main HTML)

For example if your index.html and you myfile.js are in the same directory then:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"> </script>
```

if you myfile.js is in "other/myfile.js", then:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other/myfile.js"> </script>
```

Comment: To help you ,write the console error:  ctrl+shift+i

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).textrotator is not a function
    at index2.html:44